# Getting error while executing Ienumerable<Datarow>.Sum() method.

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

Why isn't the below code working?  I am getting the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'V' to int.

```
private ObservableCollection<DataItem> method<T, V>(DataTable dt, SeriesItem seriesItem, FilterValues filter, ObservableCollection<DataItem> chart)
{
    var result = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 group t by new { type = t.Field<T>(seriesItem.LabelMapping).ToString().ToUpper() } into g
                 orderby g.Key.type
                 select new
                 {
                     Item_Type = g.Key.type.ToString(),
                     Amount = seriesItem.IsSum 
                          ? g.Sum(s => s.Field<V>(seriesItem.ValueMapping)) 
                          : g.Count()
                 };

    foreach (var g in result) 
    { 
        chart.Add(new DataItem(g.Item_Type, double.Parse(g.Amount.ToString()))
                  { 
                      IsSum = seriesItem.IsSum, 
                      IsDisplayCurrency = seriesItem.IsDisplayCurrency 
                  }); 
    }
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Wha isthe type of `seriesItem.ValueMapping`?  Forthat matter, maybe you could paste the basic public definition of SeriesItem?

Comment: Not gonna work... this aint C++ templates.

Answer (score 0):

`g.Count()` returns an int

`IsSum ? g.Sum() : g.Count()` must be an int

so `g.Sum()` must be an int

so `V` must be an int

There is nothing (other than this deduction) that stops V from being a `decimal` or anything else, hence the compiler error message.

To fix: Any of these:

- remove `V` and get int results
- remove `g.Count()`
- cast g.Count() to double and fix V's type as double.

This last one has the added benefit that you can remove the double conversion code later in the method.

---

@Daniel Renshaw

```
List<decimal> source = new List<decimal>();
int result = source.Sum<decimal>();  //compile error
  //Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'
```

Comment: `g.Sum()` can return any type that can be implicitly cast to an int or to which int can be implicitly cast

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to sum over all values of type V.

`s.Field<V>(...)` is returning a value of type V so the selector anonymous function `s => s.Field<V>(...)` is also returning a value of type V.  However, `g.Sum(...)` requires a selector function that returns values of one of the following types: `decimal`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long` (or their nullable counterparts).  It is not possible to implicitly cast from type V to any of those types.

If the value mapping column is always of a particular type then use that type explicitly instead of the generic type V.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I'm guess this bit of code returns a value of type V:

```
s => s.Field<V>(seriesItem.ValueMapping)
```

if that's the case, given that there's no constraint on the type V (it could be anything, object, string, etc. etc.) the compiler won't be able to figure out which of the overloaded [Enumerable.Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) method to invoke, hence the compiler error.

Assuming that V's type is known only at runtime (so you can't simply constraint V to int/decimal/double, etc) how about add a delegate to the method which you can use to return an int from an object of type V? e.g:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataItem> method<T, V>(DataTable dt, SeriesItem seriesItem, FilterValues filter, ObservableCollection<DataItem> chart, Func<V, int> convertV)
    {
        var result = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     group t by new { type = t.Field<T>(seriesItem.LabelMapping).ToString().ToUpper() } into g
                     orderby g.Key.type
                     select new
                     {
                         Item_Type = g.Key.type.ToString(),
                         Amount = seriesItem.IsSum ? g.Sum(s => convertV(s.Field<V>(seriesItem.ValueMapping))) : g.Count()
                     };
```

then you push the responsibility to the caller (which would know the types T and V) to figure out how to convert V to an int.